# How can I allow duplicates in Gravity Forms based on another field selection?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I want to disallow duplicate entries in Gravity Forms contextually based on a drop-down field. For instance, if someone has already entered "12345" in the text field with the drop-down set to "US", no one else could enter the same number. But if the drop-down was "UK" then they could enter "12345" no problem.

Is there an existing solution for this other than simply creating a new field for every option in the drop-down and using conditional logic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Gravity Forms Limit Submissions](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-limit-submissions/) handles this really well. You'd just set the limit to "1" and then include a rule for each field that should be counted as a unique identifier towards that limit. In your case, that'd be the Single Line Text field and your Drop Down field.